# Can Ruby on Rails Automatically generate links to articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so my question is after i generate a scaffold and i have the ability to post articles to my site it usually is a link like www.mysite.com/articles/1

my question is...is it possible to have your application automatically generate a link to your www.mysite.com/articles/1 page

because right now i have to manually go into the HTML and add the link

```
=link_to 'my article', /articles/1
```

i was just wondering if its possible to make the application automatically generate the link for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I don't know based on your question to what articles you would like to link, but if you have this set up using `resources` in your routes, this should work:

```
<ul>
  <% Article.all do |article| %>
    <li><%= link_to article.title, article %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Or if you're using HAML (as it appears you are based on the format of your question, but you don't specify:

```
%ul
  - Article.all do |article|
    %li= link_to article.title, article
```

You could modify the query to limit results, paginate them, sort them, etc. as you desire.

Comment: would i have to change something in my controller to do that?  For some reason when i try to copy and paste the code it does not throw an error but nothing shows up...i checked the source and only the ul tags appear...thats weird

Comment: Are there any articles in your database?