# how to link to different articles ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a slider with several articles a user can browse through

right now i have

html

```
 <%= link_to 'read more', @article %>
```

Controller

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
    @user = current_user
    @article = Article.find(1)
 end

 def comics
 end
 end
```

this links to the first article because it sayd find(1) but im not too sure how to write this in my controller so that i can use the same <%= link_to 'read more', @article %> and it will link to the article that i want.

i want to be able to add that link to each of my sliders and have it be directed to the proper article.

Comment: How will you know which article you want? Is this related to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831227/can-ruby-on-rails-automatically-generate-links-to-articles)? Can you not pass in an ID in the request? Most of this stuff is found in any generic Rails tutorial, btw.

Comment: You're welcome. Instead of being sarcastic, how about answering my questions so people actually have a chance of helping you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick with rails conventions and instead of *StaticPagesController* have something like *ArticlesController* as a resource (see [Resource Routing: the Rails Default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)). With this setup, you can use url helpers as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Read more", article_path(@article) %>
```

With *@article* being the current article you want to generate url for. This will route to the show action of ArticleController with the article's ID in params[:id].

Comment: i do have an articles controller...it is a resource in my routes...however I am able to link to the first article....but i'm having problems in linking to my second or third article on the same page....i generated a scaffold to post articles on my site and in my show page all the articles are listed and there are links to each article that generate by itself so i want to do something like that but not listed....i want to be able to add individual links to my slider